# break the line inside onClick (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to break the line after the appending of code.
Example:

```
string1= abc
string2= 123
```

I am geting the appending as abc 123. 
But i want it as

abc

123

```
  <input name="string1" >    
 <input name="string2" ><p>    
 <input name="showMeArea" readonly="true"><br>    
 <input type="button" value="Combine Strings"    
 OnClick="showMeArea.value= string1.value + ' ' +string2.value;"></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert a line-break in Javascript simply insert \n

showMeArea.value= string1.value + '\n' +string2.value;

Comment: Thankyou this worked.  i tried adding  < br > but it didnt work although it worked with \n .

Comment: The line break does not get inserted into the value of an `input` element.

Answer (score 1):

just add new line sign \n

```
OnClick="showMeArea.value= string1.value + '\n' +string2.value;
```

also note: you should use textarea. input field cannot display multiline text

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an escape, such as `\n` or you can just use `<br>`. The br is a line break within HTML and \n and within Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert a line break into the value of an `<input>` element with `type=text` (the default), since it is by definition for a single line of input. If you try to insert `\n` there, browsers strip it off. You need to use e.g. a `textarea` element instead. Moreover, your code that refers to elements by using their `name` attribute values as variable identifiers is obsolete and does not work in many modern browsers.

The following works:

```html
<input name="string1" id="string1">    
<input name="string2" id="string2"><p>    
<textarea name="showMeArea" id="showMeArea" readonly="true"></textarea><br>    
<input type="button" value="Combine Strings"    
OnClick="document.getElementById('showMeArea').value =
  document.getElementById('string1').value + '\n' +
  document.getElementById('string2').value;"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<script>
function combine() {
   var s1 = document.getElementById("string1").value
   var s2 = document.getElementById("string2").value
   document.getElementById("showMeArea").value = s1 +"\n\n" + s2
   document.getElementById("showMeAreaHtml").innerHTML = s1 +"<br><br>" + s2
}
</script> 
<input name="string1" id="string1">     
<input name="string2" id="string2">
<input type="button" value="Combine Strings" onclick="combine()">
<br>
<textarea name="showMeArea" id="showMeArea" readonly="true" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
<p id="showMeAreaHtml"></p>
```

Note: 
use document.getElementById is more cross browser then only name.value;
use .value for input and textarea, .innerHTML for other html elements